Blender grease pencil file more than 1GB, causes frame drops to 5 fps during playback. Any tips?
I'm relatively new and have done a couple projects already, issue is beforehand I've never had my files reach more than 1 GB in size so this issue wasn't present. It was until I've started using colors via the fill tool and all of a sudden my playback suffers fps wise. I tried looking through the internet and there are barely any answers regarding grease pencil file reduction since i believe that is the cause of the lag. Im not using any modifiers as of now and im really hoping to find answers here since the project is practically unusable in this state.
I was using blender version 4.1 beforehand facing the same issue and switched to 4.2 unfortunately facing the same problem
I have 16GB of RAM, AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU,AMD Radeon RX 5700 GPU, i know my specs arent the best but im suprised that i cant run blender at this point


Do you use a LineArt modifier? That's a consistent performance sinker. If not, it would be worth to share your file (or a mockup one if you can't share your current work), so that we can dig in and see what could be the cause. Grease Pencil can be quite complex.

I actually have no answer for Grease Pencil in particular. It is not even quite clear to me if you already had a large file more than 1 GB and it ran smoothly before you added colors with the Fill tool or if adding colors made the file larger than 1 GB and it started lagging.
So this is just what I say in general: I cannot point out often enough on this site that there is a reason why the FPS setting is in the Output properties. Blender is not a gaming engine, large complex resource-intensive scenes are not supposed to always be able to run in realtime when you start playback. Sure, it tries, but often it does not succeed.
The setting is first of all needed for correct timing of simulations matching the target FPS later on and to be used if you directly render to a video file because other than an image sequence, a video needs an FPS setting. That is why the FPS are located in the Output Properties.
If you need to check whether an animation looks correctly, do so by making a quick viewport render from the menu View > Viewport Render Animation.
If you insist on watching it in realtime in the viewport you can try to make the scene less intensive by reducing complexity of modifiers for viewport display or completely disabling the modifiers for the viewport, disabling visibility of objects that are not needed for checking the motion, disable viewport overlays etc.
But in most cases with very complex scenes you will never or hardly reach the desired target FPS, but of course this all depends on the specific scene and what there is to reduce complexity.
(Sorry, this is no real solution but it is too long for a comment and I often get told my explanatory comments seem to be qualifying as an answer and I should post them as that.)

Hmm, i guess there is no simple fix for this after all. About file size , this is my largest one yet and its a large jump (120mb to 1.08GB) from the previous even though all i've added was more colors. Another issue is that when im in this project my entire blender begins to slow down and become extremely delayed in inputs and even freezes up causing the unresponsive prompt from windows. If this is due to just straight up hardware not handling blender that would be nice to know.

@Whatisdadogdoin Is it just colors (RGB values) or textures? Maybe high resolution textures? An HDRI for the environment? Files packed into the scene or assets? Hard to tell where it comes from without the file. If the only thing that was changed is RGB values, this should not increase the size very much.

Okay this might sound weird but i remembered that I've pasted a fill onto my onto lines layer and it caused the lag in general. So i check now and delete it via multiframe causing the lag to dissapear and the file size change from 1.08GB to 81mb??? Im kind of surprised that it bugged the program out so much but seems to be fixed either way your insight is useful nontheless
