Remesh Text FPS Low (0.16)
I'm trying to animate a text with a wave modifier so I have to remesh the text for the animation to work properly. But everytime I try to play the animation my FPS go to 0.16 or less. If I try to hide the text or modify it, Blender also crashes and i have a Not responging notification. Does someone know how to fix it? Thanks

Hello and welcome. It’s important to understand the limitations of your setup before setting your voxel size too low (currently at 1mm). Doing so can generate a massive amount of geometry, which may significantly slow down or even crash the software.

Apart from what everybody already said about how unnecessary dense your mesh is, in my answer here I'm saying something about low FPS playback: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/323781/blender-grease-pencil-file-more-than-1gb-causes-frame-drops-to-5-fps-during-pla/323785#323785

This is because your Remesh modifier resolution is set to one millimeter. That’s absurdly high, generating more geometry than your computer can handle effectively.

I just did an imitation scene with the statistics overlays on. It's about 20 to 30 million triangles, depending on the scale approximation. The mesh is so dense you need to zoom in to macro level to even distinguish it, otherwise it's either all black or a nice demonstration of moiré effect. https://i.imgur.com/ixghXlS.png
